# Custom cron job status always pending

Tags: php, cron, magento-2.2.1

I created a custom cron job in my custom module. But, when I check the cron schedule, it's all in pending and don't work at all like in the picture below. Does that mean there's error on my cron job?

**Cron Job schedule :**
[image: cron]

**crontab.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="custom_crongroup">
        <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Test\Show\Cron\Test" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Cron/Test.php :**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Show\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Test {
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

/**
   * Write to system.log
   *
   * @return void
   */

    public function execute() {
        $this->logger->info('Cron Works');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the cron log for any errors.
Make sure var/log folder have 777 permissions.
If you still didn't find any solution, paste your crontab.xml file and the file your running.

Comment: 777 permission does not work, please check my crontab and cron file in my question.

Comment: have you created custom cron group named custom_crongroup ? . If you not created the group then create custom cron group or else change the group name to index/default. Already tutorials are available for creating cron groups http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

Comment: yes i created it already, and i follow that link too anyway.

Comment: Any errors in cron log ?

Comment: There's no error on cron log, nothing showed but it's all always pending

Answer (score 1):

Please Try :
Write in crontab.xml = group id="default"

To test : php bin/magento cron:run --group="default"

It will work for me

Comment: I have set index and run command but its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You must run cron twice: the first time to discover tasks to run and the second time — to run the tasks themselves. The second cron run must occur on or after the scheduled_at time for every task

Refer the [office doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)